# Encoding/decoding while web-scraping

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website into a string, but when i use decode("utf-8") on my bytes object it doesn't return a string, i instead get an UnicodeEncodeError.
I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.futbin.com/20/player/24248/leon-goretzka, which i know uses charset = "utf-8".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/24248/leon-goretzka")

text = r.text.encode("utf-8")

html = text.decode("utf-8")


print(html)
```

Comment: Where is `requests` defined? I'm assuming it's the requests library, but without the import, it's hard to tell.

Comment: `r.text` returns a string, `r.text.encode("utf-8")` returns `bytes`. I don't see the point of encoding and decoding. Why don't you just use `r.text`?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

The `get` function for `requests` needs to take an actual link. In your example, you're providing a string `"link"`.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/24248/leon-goretzka")
data = r.text
print(data)
```

This gives you a `Response` object for `r`. Using `r.text` will give you the string, `r.content` will give you bytes (which would require decoding).

Here's a link for reference: [Response example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-text-python-requests/)

Comment: I was actually already doing this. I just had a problem when trying create this question, so i removed the hyperlink. If i try your example, i still get the same error.